# ntfrs and security folders on Domain Controller

Tags: backup, domain-controller, system-state

every day Domain Controller backup reports some warnings about these files:

C:\WINDOWS\ntfrs\jet\ntfrs.jdb
C:\WINDOWS\ntfrs\jet\temp\tmp.edb
C:\WINDOWS\security\Database\secedit.sdb
C:\WINDOWS\security\edb.log
C:\WINDOWS\security\edbtmp.log
C:\WINDOWS\security\tmp.edb

They are always locked by some process and Data Protector could not backup them. As I backup the System State too, is it safe to set an excepion on these files for file system backup? Can I exclude the whole ntfrs and security folders?

Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 1):

Those the the Windows registry database files, so they are always open (as long as Windows is running). Backing up the registry through the proper utilities/facilities (e.g. ERD) will take care of any information you need to protect there.

Comment: This is partially incorrect, WINDOWS\ntfrs is related to the File Replication Service while WINDOWS\security seems to be related to Windows Security files, they are not registry databases. I agree about windows keeps opens these files but the question is if they are part of the system state or not.